# Class is not running method (simple) How do i run this?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I am having a hard time with this exercise, I am not sure why this doesn't work

**Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    conf_module.run()
TypeError: run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

**My code**

```
class Confidence:
    def __init__(self):
        self.string = 'X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475'

    def colon(self):
        self.col_pos = self.string.find(':')
        self.number = self.string[self.col_pos + 1]
        self.confidence = float(self.number)
        print(self.confidence)

    def run(self):
        self.colon()


conf_module = Confidence
conf_module.run()
```

Im sure its something simple, I just dont understand it right now. thank you for the help.

Comment: You need to instantiate the class instead of aliasing it: `conf_module = Confidence()`.

Comment: wow! that's all i had to do thanks!